# Possible VS issue Type Local not found in current namespace

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms

Build failing not finding ImageCoverter linked in xaml so I can pull binding {name} and convert it to a URL to pull images into the app.

I've added the namespace, the resource dictionary, changed the namespace, cleaned the build, manually deleted /bin /obj, everything.

Ok so I have this project, GallogForms.  Inside of that Project is GallogFroms, GallogForms.Android and GallogForms.ios.  I also have Api outside GallogForms called Gallog.Api.  All of this is being done inside GallogForms root.  I'm using NetStandarLibrary 2.0.3

ShipImageConverter.cs

```
namespace GallogForms.Images
{
    public class ShipImageConverter<T> : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return $"https://gallog.co/img/ships/{value}";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value.ToString().Replace("https://gallog.co/img/ships/", "");
        }
    }
}
```

xaml Header

```
  mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
             x:Class="GallogForms.Views.ShipsPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GallogForms.Images;assembly=GallogForms"
```

xaml ResourceDictionary

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="Primary">#2196F3</Color>
            <Color x:Key="Accent">#96d1ff</Color>
            <Color x:Key="LightTextColor">#999999</Color>
            <local:ShipImageConverter x:Key="ShipImageConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

xaml Image Source

```
 <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="8,0,8,0" BackgroundColor="#252629">
                            <Label Text="{Binding mfr}" FontFamily="zekton_regular.ttf#Zekton Rg" TextColor="White" FontSize="14" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding name}" FontFamily="zekton_regular.ttf#Zekton Rg" TextColor="White" FontSize="14" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
<Image Source="{Binding img, Converter={StaticResource ShipImageConverter}}" />
                        </StackLayout>
```

I've tried with assembly reference, without it, putting it in the root of GallogFroms putting it in the viewmodel, etc.

Expected results I've read many people with the same issue say a namespace rename has fixed the issue.  My results haven't been going so well.  I expect it to build linking ShipImageConverter inside ShipPage.xaml.

Comment: check your casing!  "Local" is not the same as "local"

Comment: Good eye, but unfortuantely, I did that writing this up.  My github where I'm copy pasting, I deleted the code to get a clean build and manually typed it up.  What gets me is intellitext is auto filling the local:ShipImageSource in the reference dictionary it's already hard coded into the list.

Comment: So,  I can't say I resolved the issue. I'd still like to get to the root of it just to know going forward, but now I replaced the converter,  directly pulling the filenames from initial list populated from my api json and I have a string that binds 2 strings right there at the source, then when the json is packed into the master list of ships, there image names are replaced with the full url to the image.   Very affective, and working inside the async method, it's much more responsive than when I hardcoded the converter using {Binding img StringFormat='{http://www.gallog.co/img/ships/{0:F0}'}"

Comment: @Dreamsforgotten Hi ,do you refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters#the-ivalueconverter-interface) to use `IValueConverter` . And if solved it , you can share answer to mark it.

Comment: So far as I can tell, the converter class is formulated properly, I'm not error-ing on any method inside of it.  I'm erroring at compile time for the file missing completely.

Comment: @Dreamsforgotten Okey , maybe something wrong not found , could you share a simple project here .

Comment: I have overwritten that completely at this point.  By putting the formatting in the async method I'm get far better results than combining the strings in xaml.  The entirety of the code I put in here at the top, But since I've successfully linked 2 other converters doing the same method, this error stated specifically the NullReference was the converter class not found.

Comment: @Dreamsforgotten Have a try with using `ShipImageConverter` to replace with `ShipImageConverter<T>` ,and restart VS .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFTyou sir are a genius.  Now I feel really dumb I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @JuniorJiang-MSFT I was missing the fact that the converter had a  Type parameter in it when linking to Xaml.